# Non_field_errors no data provided in django webapi

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and python. Now I am trying to do web API with Django and python. I can get the get request but when I request the post method, this error is shown

> "non_field_errors": [
>           "No data provided"
>       ]

View.py=>

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Allowance

from .serializers import AllowanceSerializer

# Create your views here.




class AllowanceAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,pk=None):
        if pk:
            allowance=get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
            serializer = AllowanceSerializer(allowance)
            return Response({serializer.data})
        allowance=Allowance.objects.all()
        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(allowance,many=True)
        return Response({"allowance":serializer.data})

    def post(self,request):
        allowance = request.data.get('allowance')

        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(data=allowance)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            allowance_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"success":"Allowance '{}' created successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})

    def put(self,request,pk):
        save_allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('allowance')
        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(instance=save_allowance,data=data,partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            allowance_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"sucess": "Allowance '{}' updated successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})

    def delete(self,request,pk):
        #Get object with this pk
        allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        allowance.delete()
        return Response({"message":"Allowance with id '{}' has been deleted.".format(pk)},status=204)
```

urls.py inside app =>

```
from django.conf.urls import url


from .views import AllowanceAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate')
]
```

urls.py inside project =>

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^api/auth/login/$', obtain_jwt_token, name='api-login'),
    url(r'^api/allowances_mas/', include('tmswebapi.urls')),
]
```

sample API request=>

```
{

            "AllowID": "Allow1",
            "AllowDesc": "Allow1 Description",
            "AllowAmt": "11.00",
            "AllowType": "MEAL",
            "Created_DT": "2019-06-18T18:09:00Z",
            "Created_Usr": "Admin",
            "LastModified_Usr": "",
            "LastModified_DT": "2019-06-18T18:09:00Z"
        }
```

Serializer =>

```
from rest_framework import serializers
import datetime

from .models import Allowance

class AllowanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Allowance
        fields = "__all__"

        def create(self,validated_data):
            return Allowance.objects.create(**validated_data)

        def update(self,instance,calidated_data):            
            instance.AllowDesc = validated_data.get('AllowDesc',instance.AllowDesc)
            instance.AllowAmt = validated_data.get('AllowAmt',instance.AllowAmt)
            instance.AllowType = validated_data.get('AllowType',instance.AllowType)
            instance.LastModified_Usr = "Admin"
            instance.LastModified_DT = datetime.datetime.now()

            instance.save()
            return instance
```

Is it because of urls or because of data format?

Comment: where are your serializers? Can you add them?

Comment: @JPG, Please check update

Comment: did you write *"No data provided"*  error message in your serializer?

Comment: @JPG , No , there is no message like that.

Comment: to which end-point are you sending data?

Comment: @JPG, I send allowance object.

Comment: Format is shown in the question.

Comment: I'm asking you the URL

Comment: @JPG, Oh sry, url is like that => http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/

Comment: I choose the media type is JSON and wrote the format in the content box and then click the post button.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning error from on of `if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):` lines.

It means `data` is `None` somewhere.

Debug your code to make sure `data` variable has data

Answer (score 1):

```
def post(self,request):
        allowance = request.data

        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(data=allowance)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            allowance_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"success":"Allowance '{}' created successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})
```

Now try this